# ExtJS 4.2.1 - add a top arrow to any popup menu

Tags: javascript, extjs, menu, extjs4.2

I would to create a menu with the following appearance:

[image]

I have managed to create the background color using css and the rounded corners as well.

I am now attempting to add the top arrow.

How can I add an element to the menu itself (the arrow), and shift its original open position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the `renderTpl` of the menu to include the triangle at the top.  I would recommend creating a class which extends `Ext.menu.Menu`.  See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/HMHG3/2/).

```
Ext.define('Ext.menu.TriangleMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.menu.Menu',

    initComponent: function () {
        //get the original template
        var originalTpl = Ext.XTemplate.getTpl(this, 'renderTpl');

        //add the triangle div (or img, span, etc.)
        this.renderTpl = new Ext.XTemplate([
           '<div class="menu-triangle"></div>',
           originalTpl.html,         //the html from the original tpl
           originalTpl.initialConfig //the config options from the original tpl
        ]);

        this.callParent();
    },

    beforeSetPosition: function () {
        //shift the menu down from its original position
        var pos = this.callParent(arguments);

        if (pos) {
            pos.y += 5; //the offset (should be the height of your triangle)
        }

        return pos;
    }
});
```

How you render the triangle is entirely up to you.  You can do it without having to use an image by using this neat little border trick.

```
.menu-triangle {
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-bottom: 5px solid black;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Great answer. right what I needed, but I still have a little problem, I am using frame menu so I will have rounded corners. the originalTpl only holds the menu body but it is still inside the frame... can I place it out of the frame?

Comment: That's a little trickier.  You might be able to get away with `position: absolute` on the triangle, and then playing with the other styles to get it to show up where you need it to.  You'd also have to make sure the parent `div` has `overflow: visible`, which may have some side-effects.

Comment: well again it worked like a charm, how can I set a default offset so when the menu opens its location is shifted down a bit?

Comment: Again, there's no simple way to do this.  There are likely a lot of functions you could override to get the appearance you're after.  I was able to shift it down by overriding `beforeSetPosition` (see updated answer).

Comment: wow, excellent answer, would vote you up again if I could, thanks much!